# Series Expansion Relationship

Tags: taylor-expansion

In my textbook, The Physics of Vibrations and Waves - H.J. Pain pg. 28, it states the following :

Writing
$$
S(z) = 1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{(n-1)}
$$

and
$$
z[S(z)] = z + z^2 + ... + z^n
$$

we have
$$
S(z) = (1-z^n)/(1-z)
$$

My issue is that I do not understand where the final results comes from.
I believe it may have something to do with series expansion where $1/(1-x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{(n-1)}$, but cannot figure out the relationship ...

Comment: Observe that $S(z)-zS(z)=1-z^n.$.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, thanks. I had considered that but still did not see the relationship. I thought about it again and just realised that $$ S(z)(1-z)=(1-z^n) $$ will yield the answer ...  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$z[S(z)] = z + z^2 + \dots + z^n \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=-1+1+z + z^2 + \dots + z^n  \\ \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=-1+\sum_{i=0}^nz^i \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=-1+\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \\ \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=\frac{z-1+1-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=\frac{z-z^{n+1}}{1-z} \\ \Rightarrow z[S(z)]=\frac{z(1-z^{n})}{1-z}$$ Therefore, we get $$S(z)=\frac{1-z^{n}}{1-z}$$